# Android printer connecto to multiple Android device

Tags: android, bluetooth, thermal-printer

I have successfully connected my Samsung tablet to two printer via bluetooth . Everything is good.

I try to connect another tablet to those printer, but the printer just accepts one connection at a time.

I'm thinking about set up a server Tablet that connect to the to printers, and other tablet will connect to that sever. And those devices work via bluetooth.

I just don't know if that the only possible solution. And how the Server receive and pass the order from Client to the Printers automatically.